# Automatically Load LaunchDaemon?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I wrote a little script to automatically update my Network Location based on a couple of conditions, and have coupled that with a launchd plist to have it run every couple of minutes.

However, I've noticed that my launchd plist doesn't seem to get loaded when my computer reboots.  My plist is in `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` and is fairly simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.davedelong.location-updater</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/my/location_updater.rb</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>180</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My `LaunchDaemons` folder has the expected `700` permissions, and running `launchctl load` with my plist makes things work just fine.  It's just that when I reboot, it's not getting loaded.

I was under the impression that everything in `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents` got loaded automatically by launchd.  Is this not the case?  If this is the case (and I think it is), then why isn't my plist getting loaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~/Library/LaunchDaemons` isn't a valid location for either launch agents or launch daemons. You are misunderstanding the terminology. LaunchDaemons are system-wide processes, while LaunchAgents are run per-user. From the launchd man page:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
/Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
/Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
/System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

Move your plist to `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, and it should just work.

Comment: Aha. Documentation to the rescue!