# How to make the pcscd daemon load at startup on Lion?

Tags: macos, startup, daemons

I've got an obscure cryptographic USB token that works pretty good with Lion except I need to run...

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pcscd -adf
```

...each time I want to use it because it doesn't load automatically.

How to make it load at startup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Comment: See also [Automatically Load LaunchDaemon?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30233/automatically-load-launchdaemon)

Comment: Also relative [Automatically delete a folder daily](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11243/automatically-delete-a-folder-daily/11244#11244)

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens, because securityd (which is supposed to load pcscd) does not start it when you insert your card. Try editing `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.securityd.plist` and add `-s aggressive` switch.

The section should look like this:

```
<array>
  <string>/usr/sbin/securityd</string>
  <string>-i</string>
  <string>-s</string>
  <string>aggressive</string>
</array>
```

and then reboot.

This should set securityd in aggressive card detection mode. If there is a `-s off` or anything like this, probably just removing it should solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

add the symbol & in the end of the line

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you expand on this answer a bit? What will this change and how will it help? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @Georgi, I don't think adding a & will ensure that the daemon gets started automatically after a reboot...

Comment: This is totally incorrect. The & symbol sends a command to the background and doesn't in any way change it so that it gets run again the next time the system is starting jobs.